# What is the proper way to average a set of complex numbers in c++?

Tags: c++, templates, complex-numbers

I have inherited some C++ code that needs to average some complex numbers. Given a collection, it adds those values which pass a condition to an accumulator, then divides by the number of values added.

Using gcc (currently, gcc 8) I get `template argument deduction/substitution failed` if I use stand-alone `operator/` but it works fine with `std::complex::operator/=`. Such a nuance seems fragile for follow-on maintainers.

So what is the proper way to get an average of complex numbers?

And is it reasonable that the language only partially supports division of complex numbers by integral types?

```cpp
std::complex<double> A[32] = { /* initialization left to the reader */ };
int count = 0;

std::complex<double> sum;
for (auto i = 0; i < 32; ++i) {
   if ( i % 2 ) { // arbitrary condition, not important
      sum += A[i];
      ++count;
   }
}

auto avg = sum / count; // this is ambiguous
sum /= count;           // this is not
```

*(representative error, for the curious)*

```
main.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
main.cpp:16:16: error: no match for ‘operator/’ (operand types are ‘std::complex<double>’ and ‘int’)
 auto avg = sum / count; // this is ambiguous
            ~~~~^~~~~~~
In file included from main.cpp:2:0:
/usr/include/c++/7/complex:434:5: note: candidate: template<class _Tp> std::complex<_Tp> std::operator/(const _Tp&, const std::complex<_Tp>&)
     operator/(const _Tp& __x, const complex<_Tp>& __y)
     ^~~~~~~~
/usr/include/c++/7/complex:434:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
main.cpp:16:18: note:   mismatched types ‘const std::complex<_Tp>’ and ‘int’
 auto avg = sum / count; // this is ambiguous
                  ^~~~~
In file included from main.cpp:2:0:
/usr/include/c++/7/complex:425:5: note: candidate: template<class _Tp> std::complex<_Tp> std::operator/(const std::complex<_Tp>&, const _Tp&)
     operator/(const complex<_Tp>& __x, const _Tp& __y)
     ^~~~~~~~
/usr/include/c++/7/complex:425:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
main.cpp:16:18: note:   deduced conflicting types for parameter ‘const _Tp’ (‘double’ and ‘int’)
 auto avg = sum / count; // this is ambiguous
                  ^~~~~
In file included from main.cpp:2:0:
/usr/include/c++/7/complex:416:5: note: candidate: template<class _Tp> std::complex<_Tp> std::operator/(const std::complex<_Tp>&, const std::complex<_Tp>&)
     operator/(const complex<_Tp>& __x, const complex<_Tp>& __y)
     ^~~~~~~~
/usr/include/c++/7/complex:416:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
main.cpp:16:18: note:   mismatched types ‘const std::complex<_Tp>’ and ‘int’
 auto avg = sum / count; // this is ambiguous
                  ^~~~~
```

Comment: Have you tried `sum / double(count)`?

Comment: yes, I know I can do an explicit cast. And that is how I get around the error/ambiguity to keep going. I guess this is a more philosophical question than a pragmatic one

Comment: Opinion: Absolutely reasonable that the language only partially supports.  Your template is to the type double.  therefore doubles get special treatment relative to your template.  You are welcome to define the operation for other types as you see fit or even change the operation relative to doubles.

Comment: As converting an integer to floating point might lose accuracy, philosophically I'd expect support for division of a float by an integer. AFAIK, no processor actually supports division of a float by an integer, so I can see why C++ standard doesn't either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what the most proper way to do division for it, but if you look through all the parameters `operator/` and `operator/=` take, you would notice that:

- `operator/` takes in either `std::complex<T>` or `T`.

  - So if you have your original complex created with `double`, then it should only take in another value that is either `double` or `complex<double>`.
  - In fact, depends on the compiler you are using, `clang` straight up gave `invalid operands to binary expression ('std::complex<double>' and 'int')` error
- `operator/=` takes in `std::complex<T>` or `T`, while also have specialization for `float`, `double`, and `long double`.

  - That means whatever passed to `operator/=` would have a change to be implicit converted to `float`, `double`, or `long double`, which `int` can do.

Comment: is this part of the mystical world of template type deduction, where implicit conversion does not apply? If I understand what you are saying, `operator/=` has an explicit specialization for `float` (for example) but `operator/` does not?

Comment: @Jwm That's exactly what I mean. Remember that `T` was deduced to `double` when you constructed `std::complex<double> sum`.